# requireJS Shim Export property

Tags: requirejs

Hi I have just started reading requireJS and come to point about shim configuration I understand that part too but confused in one requirejs Api statement says "The global Backbone will still exist on the page too."

"Then, later in a separate file, call it 'MyModel.js', a module is
defined, specifying 'backbone' as a dependency. RequireJS will use
the shim config to properly load 'backbone' and give a local
reference to this module. The global Backbone will still exist on
the page too."

whats this means the global Backbone will still exist on the page too.

can anyone explain.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means backbone will be define at the global(window.backbone) level AND as a module

Comment: Thanks Richard, so if i understood correct i can access backbone.js by backbone or window.backbone but what will be difference here?

Comment: no difference, it depends if you want to track dependencies calling backbone as a module (that's what I do)